# applications using ribbon

Tags: ribbon-control

We're looking for applications that implemented the ribbon control just to see how developers other than MS Office team used this control. I tried googling a bit but the list is still short. Can you guys refer me to some good projects that are using the ribbon control the right way?

Thanks,
MR

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers some samples if you're looking for implementation details. Or are you looking more for design ideas?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks, we're looking for some other non-Microsoft product though. AutoCAD 2009 would be one example. We're looking for more.